# How exactly does 'Community' randomly decide to bump posts?

Tags: discussion, community

I'd imagine this information is somewhere but I looked for a while and couldn't find anything in the FAQ or in a previous question.

Does anyone have any information about how exactly Community decides which posts to bump and when? I got the idea that it bumps posts that have no accepted answers but beyond that its algorithm is a mystery to me. The reason I asked is that the [most recent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10718/steels-method-for-nonparametric-multiple-comparison-with-control) bump seemed to me to be a pretty low quality post that only lacks an "accepted" answer because the OP abandoned the question and never accepted a pretty definitive answer (although the 'definitive answer' is pretty vacuous since the OP could've just googled in the first place to find this out, which leads me back to the 'low quality post' comment).

So, is it just a random selection from the list of questions without accepted answers or is it something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, all the info about the SE engine itself is on The Meta, i.e. [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). An answer to your question is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690/148927).