# Follow-up question to a question with an accepted answer

Tags: discussion

I am just double-checking on this. If I have a followup question to an existing question where I already have accepted an answer. I should post it as a new question right?

For example asking to clarify if a Gains or lift chart's deciles are based on top propensity scores for either classification in the case of a binary target. This would be branching of this original [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33148/what-do-lift-and-gain-charts-state-in-the-context-of-an-employee-turnover-model).

I feel like I should just add it to the comments but think no one will respond since the question is already answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your followup question is really different, just ask a new question with a link to the older thread. I would say it is better to have some supporting data or updated context for this, so that it doesn't look like a duplicate.

You might also want to take a look at this related question: [What is the best way to ask a follow up or slightly revised question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1259/930)

Re:

> I feel like I should just add it to the comments but think no one will
>   respond since the question is already answered.

You can slightly edit your question so that it will bump up in the queue of active questions and upvote new comments so that they remain visible.