# What to do if we need to update a question if there's already answering effort?

Tags: discussion

I put a lot of effort into a [question about difficulties in reproducing a specific algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/431720/163114). I got stuck in one step, was able to (probably) find a solution myself, but got stuck again in a next step. I've now edited the question showing the solution I have found and where I'm stuck. Anyway, the topic hasn't changed and I'm still having trouble reproducing this algorithm.

But there was already an answer - which however was not really an answer (so this question doesn't really match up with this [related meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1159/163114)) because it did not help to even solve the first step I was stuck. I know it's not recommended to edit questions when there is already an answer, in order not to produce "chameleons" but I thought it would not have made sense to ask a new question where most of the text is the same.

I have now <strike>crossed out</strike> the text passages that were wrong and inserted a new chapter **"Edit"** to make it visible that I've made an update. I think the question has a higher value now, but I wanted to know if this was the right thing to do. Or -- to get a "w" into my question -- what should we do when we found a solution ourselves but got stuck in the next step if there's already a - but poor - answer?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that it should be better to ask new question. First, because it was already answered. Second, from practical point of view, if you edit your question it would faster disappear from the main page, then if you asked new one, so asking new one gives you better visibility and chance of it getting answered. Third, asking a new question may give you a chance to reword it and make it more clear, as opposed to adding "EDIT" sections that in most cases make the question more confusing and messy. Also, adding new question gives you a chance to think on what exactly is the aspect of the question that was not covered by the previous one, so that it deserves a new question.